# Are the sand dunes at Knolls, UT safe to visit?

Tags: beaches, utah, dunes

There are very nice sand dunes at Knolls, UT, just off of I-80.  However, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knolls,_Utah), Knolls is also a site of a hazardous dump, at Grassy Mountain.

Are the sand dunes in Knolls safe to visit?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Knolls Recreation Area Page](http://www.utahoutdooractivities.com/knolls.html): Yes as long as you don't enter the bombing range:

> If you travel south you will come to a fence, if you cross this you will be entering the Dugway bombing range, not a good place to be. So stay in bounds and watch for the fences, which are clearly marked, and you'll be ok.